# How to install jnetpcap library on Raspberry pi (Rasbian OS)?

Tags: raspberry-pi, debian, iot, jnetpcap

Can anyone help. I want to capture packets using jnetpcap library. But I'm getting Java build path errors.

I think i have not installed the library properly. I tried with the jnetpcap library for Debian version. What do I have to download and put which version and how to copy it to global environment. `.so` file and `.jar` files if needed.

I installed libcap-dev too.

Comment: what is the command that you run and the error that you received ?

Comment: Did you finally solve it?